# Making HTML onClick events conditional

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, conditional-statements

I've asked this question before, and got it to be functional in ie7. Since then, we upgraded to IE 8 and I can not find a way to make it work. I have a form that is manually filled out by the user, and when they click copy, the form is concatenated into a single text box with formatting applied. I need the formatting to be conditional, so if certain parts of the form are not entered or left blank, they do not leave an empty line break in the formatting. Example Form:

```
<body>
<form name="data_entry" id="frm1"

<tr>
<td>Name of Person:</td>
<td><textarea name="name" rows="2" cols="30" id="name"></textarea></td>
</tr><br>

<tr>
<td>Type of Service:</td>
<td><select name="drop1" id="txt_drop1">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="Type of Service: Minimal">Minimal</option>
    <option value="Type of Service: Normal">Normal</option>
    <option value="Type of Service: Full">Full</option>
    <option value="Type of Service: Premium">Premium</option>
</select></td>
</tr><br>

<tr>
<td>Dollar Amount:</td>
<td><textarea name="amount" rows="1" cols="30" id="txt_info2"></textarea></td>
</tr><br>

<tr>
<td><textarea name="bigtextbox" rows="5" cols="30" id="txt_info2"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</form>
</body>

<input type="button" style="font-weight:bold;" name="clipboard_copy" value="Copy" onClick="document.data_entry.bigtextbox.value = 'Name:&nbsp;' + document.data_entry.name.value + '\n' + document.data_entry.drop1.value + '\n' + 'Amount: $' + document.data_entry.amount.value">

</body>
```

The result Im looking to acheive is to have it look like so if the "type of service" value is empty: 
 
**Name: John Smith 

Amount:$123** 
 

Rather than: 
 
**Name: John Smith 


Amount:$123**  
It would also need to work for cases where they leave any other field blank. 
Thanks in advance, and sorry for the repeat question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function validate() {
        var value = '';

        try {
            if (document.data_entry.name.value.length > 0) {
                value += 'Name: ' + document.data_entry.name.value + '\n';
            }

            if (document.data_entry.drop1.selectedIndex > 0) {
                value += document.data_entry.drop1[document.data_entry.drop1.selectedIndex].value + '\n';
            }

            if (document.data_entry.amount.value.length > 0) {
                value += 'Amount: $' + document.data_entry.amount.value;
            }

            document.data_entry.bigtextbox.value = value;
        }
        catch (Error) {
            alert(Error);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="data_entry" id="frm1">

<tr>
<td>Name of Person:</td>
<td><textarea name="name" rows="2" cols="30" id="name"></textarea></td>
</tr><br>

<tr>
<td>Type of Service:</td>
<td><select name="drop1" id="txt_drop1">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="Type of Service: Minimal">Minimal</option>
    <option value="Type of Service: Normal">Normal</option>
    <option value="Type of Service: Full">Full</option>
    <option value="Type of Service: Premium">Premium</option>
</select></td>
</tr><br>

<tr>
<td>Dollar Amount:</td>
<td><textarea name="amount" rows="1" cols="30" id="txt_info2"></textarea></td>
</tr><br>

<tr>
<td><textarea name="bigtextbox" rows="5" cols="30" id="txt_info2"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</form>
</body>

<input type="button" style="font-weight:bold;" name="clipboard_copy" value="Copy" onClick="validate();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm assuming this means, set the onlick up like so: document.data_entry.name.value + '\n' + (document.data_entry.drop1.value.length > 0) ? document.data_endry.drop1.value + '\n' : '') +  document.data_entry.drop1.value

Comment: Essentially yes. You could actually do it to all the values (depending on which are required or not and if you have validation in place). Also, you may need to obtain the value from the drop down by entering the collection "document.data_entry.drop1[document.data_entry.drop1.selectedIndex].value"

Comment: Also, as Max mentioned, you really should move this to a function rather than inlining it.

Comment: I can't comment on your question in Max's response, but since your putting the information into another HTML control, to get rid of the &nbsp; just use the space character. If you were putting the information onto the page you could use &nbsp;

Comment: Here is the link for the ternary operator in javascript for reference since you mentioned you were new to it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I would prefer to have it as a function as well, which is what I'm trying to straighten out and figure out, right now, just wanted to gain a bit more understanding about the method you described though, which you answered my question very well!

Comment: but do you know why it puts "undefined" at the beginning of the method max stated?

Comment: I updated my response to give you the full solution. I took out the ternary operator just for clarity. If it helps please remember to up vote

Comment: Perfect! It now works without returning the "undefined" error in the big text box. <3

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you'll want to have your onClick event on `clipboard_copy` refer to a separate function. For instance:

`onClick="validate()"`

Your function can use simple if statements to format your output properly:

```
function validate() {
     var value;
     if (document.data_entry.bigtextbox.value.length > 0) value += 'Name:&nbsp;' +
     document.data_entry.name.value + '\n';
     if (document.data_entry.drop1.value.length > 0) value += document.data_entry.drop1.value + '\n';
     if (document.data_entry.amount.value.length > 0) value += 'Amount: $' + document.data_entry.amount.value;

    document.data_entry.bigtextbox.value = value;
}
```

Real functions give you a lot more power than that inline onclick stuff.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense, I'm just not very good with Javascript yet. How do I make it not return the "&nbsp" as text? and how i stop it from putting "undefined" at the beginning every time copy is clicked?